# Append in form doesn't work in Vue.js component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, append

This is my template:

```
<form class="form-inline editableImage" @submit.prevent="upload">
    ...
</form>
```

This is my script:

```
methods: {
    upload: function() {
        let data = new FormData();
        data.append('foo', 'bar');
        console.log('data', data);
    }
}
```

`console.log` shows:

```
data FormData {}
    __proto__: FormData
```

Why is `data` empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it's not empty. You can check your data by using `get(key)` method. `console.log(data.get('foo'));` should show you `'bar'`